# How much does it cost to publish a Firefox add-on on addons.mozilla.org?

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla

I plan to develop some Firefox add-ons but I'm not sure if publishing it on Firefox store is free unlike Chrome webstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing an add-on to Firefox addon marketplace is free. Have a look at [this](https://isantoshv.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/publishing-your-browser-add-on-to-firefox-add-on-marketplace/) for a step by step procedure on publishing your first browser add-on to AMO( addons.mozilla.org ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's free you just need to sign it by Mozilla signing API and that's it.

Comment: There is no need for a separate signing step. By uploading it to AMO, and passing review, the add-on will automatically be signed. You don't have to do anything extra.